# Adding a sleep() function after API call

Tags: python

I have a script that is trying to scrape data that looks as such. If you run this script as it is (with your login credentials added to `user_name` and `password`) It will normally run fine, but that's because its only evaluating 10 records.

```
from ftplib import error_proto
from hashlib import new
from multiprocessing.spawn import import_main_path
from time import sleep
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from collections import Counter
import datetime
import os.path

all_followers = [['483604402', '000joel000'], ['37453815745', '01erregina'], ['5970797189', '01siungit'], ['315051477', '09oneinamillion'], ['641990286', '0two1000'], ['5772189196', '101ilovegod'], ['6819315251', '10k_a_daytw'], ['16874398', '111insta_user'], ['35045822961', '1171.murat'], ['42584594048', '1252santosh']]

user_name = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXXX"

api = Client(user_name, password)

def get_bios(followers):
    bios = []
    for follower in followers:
        follower_id = follower[0]
        bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
    return bios

bios = get_bios(all_followers)

def print_bios():
    s = ''
    for row in bios:
        s += '\n' + 'user_id: ' + str(row[0]) + ', bio: ' + str(row[1])
    print(s)
```

But let's say I wanted to add `sleep(60)` after every time it made an API call so that it reduces the time made between API calls. Where would that go in the script?

Would it go here?

```
def get_bios(followers):
        bios = []
        for follower in followers:
            follower_id = follower[0]
            bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
            sleep(60)
        return bios
```

Or would it go:

```
def get_bios(followers):
    bios = []
    for follower in followers:
        follower_id = follower[0]
        bios += [[follower_id, api.user_info(follower_id)['user']['biography']]]
    return bios

bios = get_bios(all_followers)
sleep(60)
```

Or perhaps somewhere else?

Comment: if you want to sleep after each time a value gets filled in the bios list variable. Go with the first one

Comment: This looks like a job for `aiohttp` and `async`

Comment: yes you can definetly use threading in this to bump up the speed by a lot. As we all know how slow is python

Comment: @TanayMishra But the goal is to slow it down, not speed it up, to avoid exceeding the API's rate limit.

Comment: Correct the goal is to slow down, not speed up. So where would it be best to position the `sleep(60)` function? Would it be my first example?

Comment: it would be the first example, so that it sleeps after each API call.  The second example would just make it sleep once after all the followers were processed.